# strip out value from return using awk

Tags: awk, grep, iptables

Im not sure how to strip out the "DST=" from these lines..
Here is my command(its returning what it should) and please if there is a more efficient way or a better way, feel free to criticize.

```
awk '{print $10}' iptables.log |sort -u

DST=96.7.49.64
DST=96.7.49.65
DST=96.7.50.64
DST=98.27.88.26
DST=98.27.88.28
DST=98.27.88.45
DST=98.27.88.50
```

As you can see, I need to grab unique ip's from iptable log.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can keep it all in one process, and use awk's equivalent `sub()` function, i.e.

```
awk '{sub(/DST=/,"",$10); print $10}' iptables.log |sort -u
```

**Update:**

> Is there anyway to key just on DST= regardless of whether its at space 10 or 11?

```
awk '$10~/^DST=/{sub(/DST=/,"",$10); print $10};$11~/^DST=/{sub(/DST=/,"",$11); print $11}' iptables.log | sort -u
```

OR

```
awk '{for (i=9;i<13;i++) {
 if ($i ~ /^DST=/) { sub(/DST=/, "", $i); print $i}
 }
}' iptables.log | sort -u
```

Note that here, you can change the range of fields to check and print, I'm testing  fields 9-12 just for example. variables in awk like `$i` refer to the `i'th'` element in the current line, just like $1, $9, $87, etc, etc.

As I don't have iptables.log to test with, I can't test it except to confirm that the awk syntax doesn't fail. It this doesn't work, please post 2-4 sample lines of simplified data.

IHTH

Comment: You guys rock..this works..so its more efficient to keep it all in one correct..I know captain obvious, just making sure, this will be running every 2 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: It all depends, but in many/most cases, the fewer the processes the better. Watch @Steve for an update, if unsorted data works for you that will be the most efficient. Good luck to all.

Comment: I have an update..this was working but my iptables changed format and added a space, but not all the time..so i changed $10 to $11 and it worked but then some were back at 10 :( Is there anyway to key just on DST= regardless of whether its at space 10 or 11? Let me know if you need the exact log entries to show.

Comment: AWESOME! thanks so much..that did it! any recommendations for me to learn awk usage like this? ie. a book or some kind of training? Thanks again!

Comment: I love the original book about awk, 'The awk programming Language' written the *A*ho, *W*einbererg and *K*erninghan (hence the name awk). Try searching for a reasonably priced copy http://www.fetchbook.info/compare.do?search=9780201079814. The gawk book by Arnold D. Robbins, covers all the new features supported in gawk, A must read has well.

Comment: Also if you work thru all of the tutorials under http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/ you''ll be in very good shape. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you you don't mind the unsorted output, here's a better way using `awk`:

```
awk '!a[$10]++ { sub(/DST=/,"",$10); print $10 }' file
```

Comment: This one didnt work, but thank you! This returned the entire iptable log instead of just the dst and stripping it.

Comment: @sectech: Yes, I forgot to `print $10` in the [last version](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14867393/revisions). Did you try the updated code? HTH.

Comment: @sectech: You may want to try that again. I can assure you that `DST=` string will be removed from field 10.

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe the result of your output through sed to remove the DST= from each line:

```
awk '{print $10}' iptables.log | sed 's/^DST=//' | sort -u
```

Comment: Thanks!! That was perfect! good old awk/sed :)  sometimes I hate coming from a windows background.

Comment: Thanks for the cred, but @shelter had a much more elegant solution (as I'm sure you noticed!)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{split($10,a,"=");b[a[2]];next}END{for(i in b)print i}' iptables.log
```